# Return JavaScript object keys that share the same value without knowing key name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a simple JavaScript object:

```
 {"omar":"espn.com","omar1":"espn1.com","omar3":"espn.com"}
```

How do I return all keys that share `"espn.com"` without knowing the name of the keys?

In this case, only `"omar"` and `"omar3"` should be returned.

Comment: `Object.keys` and `Array#filter` should be enough

Comment: Are you looking for a specific value...or just any that have a match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just enumerate the properties with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the ones you want.

#### Working Example:

```js
var o = {"omar":"espn.com","omar1":"espn1.com","omar3":"espn.com"};

var matched = Object.keys(o).filter(function(key) {
    return o[key] === 'espn.com';
});

console.log(matched);
```